# Python connecting SSAS with pyadomd

Tags: python, ssas

I've connected to my SSAS Cube using Python, however I'm having some problems with executing the MDX query. Here is the code that I've used:

```
from sys import path

path.append('\\Program Files\\Microsoft.NET\\ADOMD.NET\\140')

from pyadomd import Pyadomd


conn_str = 'connection_str'
query = """mdx_query"""

with Pyadomd(conn_str) as conn:
    with conn.cursor().execute(query) as cur:
        print(cur.fetchall())
```

I've checked connection using `print(conn.state)` and everything is ok.

The error that I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kkrukows/PycharmProjects/test/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    with conn.cursor().execute(query) as cur:
  File "C:\Users\kkrukows\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\pyadomd\pyadomd.py", line 71, in execute
    adomd_type_map[self._reader.GetFieldType(i).ToString()].type_name
KeyError: 'System.Object'
```

Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please upgrade the package to version 0.0.6 and try again.

You can do that using pip:

`pip install pyadomd --upgrade`